# AWS IoT active provisioning template does nothing

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

Let me preface this by saying that I am very new to IoT, so I might just be doing something completely wrong.

I created a Certificate Authority, registered it with AWS IoT. The status is Active and has Automatic certificate registration enabled.

I also created this policy called `iot_test_policy`(which is very permissive on purpose):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I created a JITP provisioning template with this policy:

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "policy_iot_test_policy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IoT::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "iot_test_policy"
      }
    },
    "certificate": {
      "Type": "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
      "Properties": {
        "CertificateId": {
          "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id"
        },
        "Status": "Active"
      }
    },
    "thing": {
      "Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing",
      "OverrideSettings": {
        "AttributePayload": "MERGE",
        "ThingGroups": "DO_NOTHING",
        "ThingTypeName": "REPLACE"
      },
      "Properties": {
        "AttributePayload": {},
        "ThingGroups": [],
        "ThingName": {
          "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName"
        },
        "ThingTypeName": "test-type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I made sure to turn everything to 'active' or 'enabled', especially the `Automatic certificate registration` and `Automatically create a thing resource when provisioning a device` toggles.

Now when I run a Python script that tries to establish a connection using a cert and private key generated using my own CA (the one that is registered with AWS IoT), the only thing that happens is the certificate showing up in the `security/certificates` tab but with a status of `PENDING_ACTIVATION`.

My assumption was that the provisioning template would see that IoT device which has 'credentials' that were signed/created using a known CA, that it would create a 'thing', attach it to the credentials and add the correct policy. But this doesn't seem to be happening.

When I register the credentials, add it to a thing and add a policy manually, the script works perfectly fine. So I assume the keys are fine.

What am I missing / doing wrong for the provisioning templates to work?

Comment: Hi, could you solve the issue or find a workaround ?
I stumbled across the same issue.

I opened a issue at the aws iot device sdk python v2 github page and linked your post there.
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/issues/531

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into the same issue where performing the JITP flow causes the registered certificates to be under pending validation, I was following the [AWS IoT Device Management Workshop](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/7c2b04e7-8051-4c71-bc8b-6d2d7ce32727/en-US) and experienced the same thing too. The cause was the provisioning template itself.

The provisioning template had a section with `ThingGroups` with a value of `bulk-group`, and I did not have the `bulk-group` created on my AWS IoT Thing Groups.

```
"ThingGroups": [
    "bulk-group"
]
```

I then removed that section out of the provisioning template and removed the certificate that was pending verification on AWS IoT, then reconnected with client with the certificate through JITP flow and it worked fine.

So for anyone running into the same issue, do check again the properties in the provisioning template.